How can I resolve the white screen issue during video transitions in React?
I have a loop of MP4 videos in my React application. However, when I click a button, I want another MP4 video to start playing. But as soon as I click the button, there's a momentary white screen for about 1 second before the other video starts playing. How can I prevent this white screen from appearing?
// VideoPlayer.jsx

import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { VideoContext } from "../context/VideoContext";

const VideoPlayer = () => {
  const { activeVideo, videos, setActiveVideo } = useContext(VideoContext);
  const [loop, setLoop] = useState(null);

  const isLoop = () => {
    if (activeVideo === videos.cam1Fixed || activeVideo === videos.cam2Fixed) {
      setLoop(true);
    } else {
      setLoop(false);
    }
  };

  const onEnded = () => {
    if (!loop) {
      setActiveVideo(videos.cam2Fixed);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    isLoop();
  }, [activeVideo]);

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-full absolute top-0 left-0 z-[-1]">
      <video
        onEnded={onEnded}
        className="w-full h-full object-cover"
        src={activeVideo}
        autoPlay
        muted
        loop={loop}
      ></video>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;


// ChangeCamButton.jsx

import { useContext } from "react";
import { VideoContext } from "../context/VideoContext";

const ChangeCamButton = () => {
  const { setActiveVideo, videos } = useContext(VideoContext);

  const changeCam = () => {
    setActiveVideo(videos.cam1Transition);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={changeCam} className="text-white text-xl bg-red-600 rounded-md p-3 bg-opacity-90 hover:bg-red-500 transition-all">
      Change Camera
    </button>
  );
};

export default ChangeCamButton;

// VideoContent.jsx

import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import videos from "../utils/index";

const VideoContext = createContext();

const VideoProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [activeVideo, setActiveVideo] = useState(videos.cam1Fixed);

  return (
    <VideoContext.Provider value={{ activeVideo, setActiveVideo, videos }}>
      {children}
    </VideoContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { VideoContext, VideoProvider };

// App.jsx

import "./App.css";
import VideoPlayer from "./components/VideoPlayer";
import { VideoProvider } from "./context/VideoContext";
import ChangeCamButton from "./components/ChangeCamButton";

function App() {
  return (
    <VideoProvider>
      <VideoPlayer />
      <ChangeCamButton />
    </VideoProvider>
  );
}

export default App;


Sounds like the white screen you're seeing is due to the video being loaded when you change it. Something you could do to avoid this would be to have multiple video tags with the possible video streams and hiding/showing them as needed. The transition should be more "seamless" but definitely consumes more bandwidth.

How could I not think of this method! Thanks so much for your guidance. Thanks to you, I achieved the result I wanted. As for bandwidth. My first ultimate goal was to achieve what I wanted, but I am aware that I should not neglect performance. Assuming there are 10 mp4 files, each averaging 30-50 MB, do you think this is an acceptable solution in terms of performance and bandwidth?
Or do you think there might be a more reasonable solution than this?

I'd say it depends. Is this a public application that'll be accessible from the Internet? Or is this running locally only for you? 300mb is a lot especially for a single page, and someone with a bad Internet connection speed will have a miserable time trying to use your app. I'm not sure if serving your videos through HLS or MPEG-DASH would be better since they're chunk-based streaming protocols and wouldn't require your browser to download the entirety of the 10 videos.
